# How can I implement an IRC Server with 'owned' nicknames?

Tags: networking, distributed, protocols, irc

Recently, I've been reading up on the IRC protocol (RFCs 1459, 2810-2813), and I was thinking of implementing my own server.

I'm not necessarily looking into adhering religiously to the IRC protocol (I'm doing this for fun, after all), but one of the things I do like about it is that a network can consist of multiple servers transparently.

There are a number of things I don't like about the protocol or the IRC specification. The first is that nicknames aren't owned. While services like NickServ exist, they're not part of the official protocol. On the *other* hand, implementing something like NickServ *properly* kind of defeats the purpose of distribution (i.e. there'd be one place where NickServ is running, and one data store for it).

I was hoping there'd be a way to manage nicknames on a per-server basis. The problem with this is that if you have two servers that have some registered nicknames, and they then link up, you can have collisions.

Is there a way to avoid this, without using one central data store? That is: is it possible to keep the servers loosely connected (such that they each exist as an independent entity, but can also connect to one another) and maintain uniqueness amongst nicknames?

I realize this question is vague, but I can't think of a better way of wording it. I'm looking more for suggestions than I am for actual yes/no answers. So if anyone has any ideas as to how to accomplish nickname uniqueness in a network while still maintaining server independence, I'd be interested in hearing it. Note that adhering strictly to the IRC protocol isn't at all necessary; I've got no problem changing things to suit my purposes. :)

Comment: The question for me is 'Good God why???".

Comment: For fun. That's what we're here for: FUN. :)

Comment: mipadis answer reminded me: look into XMPP/Jabber. It's a more capable, modern protocol and implementing that for fun might be more useful and it supports what you want automagically.

Comment: @FreeMemory: I do not consider it 'fun' to have another implementation of something like IRC that doesn't even follow the RFC around. Please, for the love of all that is holy, find some other project...

Comment: @Rich B: Isn't that a myopic view of programming? That's like saying to a writer, "Don't write that detective novel; Sir Arthur Conan Doyle already did it." Sure, it's been done. But programming should be fun and interesting. I don't intent to foist my creations on the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple solution *if* you don't care about *strictly* implementing an IRC server, but rather implementing a distributed message system that's *like* IRC, but not *exactly* IRC.

The simple solution is to use nicknames in the form "nick@host", much like email. So instead of merely being "mipadi", my nickname could be "mipadi@free-memorys-server.net". So I register with just your server, but when your server links up with others to form another a big ole' chat network, you can easily union all the usernames together. There might be a "mipadi" on otherserver.net, but then our nicknames become "mipadi@free-memorys-server.net" and "mipadi@otherserver.net", and everything is cool.

Of course, this deviates a good deal from IRC. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's Jabber-like, although, hey, I'm not opposed to that. My only issue, I think, is that, in general, users don't want to remember that they registered with X server. They want to be able to just "log in."

Comment: True, but generally, IRC users have to remember which server to connect to, so it shouldn't be hard to remember which server they registered with.

Comment: I can't believe I am going to lend advice to this awfulness, but you could always have whatever server they connect to authenticate them with whatever server they are specifying as their nickname anyway.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be aware of each other.  If not, you cannot prevent the sharing of nicknames.  If they are, you simply need to transfer updates on the back-end.  To prevent simultaneous registrations, you need a transaction system that blocks, requests permission from all other servers, and responds.

To prevent simultaneous registrations during outages, you have no choice but to timestamp the registration, and remove all but the last (or a random for truly simultaneous) registered copy of the nick.

It's not very pretty considering these servers aren't initially merged in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could still implement nick ownership without a central instance, *if* your server instances trust each other.

- When a user registers a nick, it is registered with the current server he's connected with
- When a server receives a registration that it didn't know of, it forwards that information to all other servers that don't know it yet (might need a smart algorithm to avoid spamming the network)
- When a server re-connects to another server then it tries to synchronize the list of registered nicks and which server handles which nick
- If there is a collision during that sync, then the older registration is used, and the newer one marked as invalid

If you can't trust your servers, then it'll get a lot harder, as a servers could easily claim every username and even claim the oldest registration for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to come up with something new, the idea that springs to mind, is simply including something unique about the server as part of the nick name when communicating outside of the server.  So if you want to message a user on a different server you might have something like user@server

If you don't need them to be completely separate you might want to consider creating some kind of multiple-master replicated database of accounts.  Where each server stores a complete copy of the account database, and each server can create new accounts which will be replicated to other servers as possible.  You'll probably still have to deal with collisions on occasion though.

Answer (score 0):

> While services like NickServ exist, they're not part of the official protocol.

Services are not part of the official protocol because they've nothing to do with the protocol. They're bots with permissions. There's no reason why you couldn't have one running on each server but it does make them harder to maintain.

If you were to go down that path, I would probably suggest the commonly used "multiple master" database replication technique. If one receives a write (in your case, a new user is created or updated, etc) it sends the data to all the other nodes. You'll have to be careful though. If one node is offline when the others get an update, it will need to know to resync on reconnection.

Another technique would be as above but in reverse. Data is only exchanged between nodes when it's needed. Eg if a user tries to log in on a node where there's no data for it, it'll query the others and issue a move order to get all the data to that one node. This is potentially less painful than the replication version but there could be severe problems in netsplits if somebody signs up on a node disconnected from the pack for a duplicate nick.

One technique to nullify the problems of netsplits would be to make chat nodes and their bots netsplit-aware. When they're split, they probably shouldn't allow any write actions... But this could impact on your network if you're splitting lots.

You've also got to ask how secure this might or might not be. IRC network nodes are distributed for performance but they're not "secure". Because of this, service bots are usually run centrally to keep ultimate control over their running. If you distributed the bots and remote node got hacked, they'd potentially have access to the whole user database (depending on the model).